# Packet sequence number wrong - got 2 expected 0

Tags: mysql, pymysql

I used my script to do a batch scan of the database，But my program reported something wrong

```
Packet sequence number wrong - got 2 expected 0
```

```
            for ip_port in ip_ports:
                    db_info.update(ip_port)
                    for port_str in db_info['port_list']:
                        try:
                            port_int = int(port_str)
                            self._conn = pymysql.connect(
                                host = db_info['host_ip'],
                                user='jmysql',
                                password='addcn123',
                                database=None,
                                port = port_int)
                            self._cursor = self._conn.cursor()
                        except Exception as e:
                            print(e)
                        continue
```

Comment: Has anyone told me what happened？

Comment: please post the code that produces that error. also check your tables

Comment: I loop through connect the database，The first connection is fine, but the second connection is wrong

Comment: you should rethink your logic, you try different port on one ip with the same credentials, so use all static information from db_info, also don't create  port_list you update the port in every loop till you find your candidate, so you shold print the rror, that is counterproductive, and with the update db_info with the right port, you can always connect to the database with db_info, and next time you start your program run the sequence again to find the port